# What has happened with the Publications of the $n$Lab?

Tags: journals, online-resources, peer-review

What has happened with the [Publications of the $n$Lab](https://ncatlab.org/publications/published/HomePage)? They seem to have published only a couple of articles back in 2011, 2012. A little search i made was not very enlightening.

Has the project been discontinued? If yes why?

(In principle, the idea seemed to be pursuing an alternative, electronic,  publishing system with a public and transparent peer-review process. But it seems it didn't work as expected. Was the focus too narrowlly limited? Or is there some other reason?)

Comment: You can **also** ask on https://nforum.ncatlab.org/

Comment: Sadly, the current system of academia actively disincentivises such novel experiments. It's hard enough to set up a new journal to effectively replace a journal run by some for-profit shareholder-pleasing company, although it has been done, with a lot of goodwill and determination by sub-communities of the mathematics world. Setting up a wiki-journal is even less respected.

Comment: The Steering Committee of the nLab (which doesn't run it, officially) hasn't done a post-mortem, or tried to dig into why it didn't take off. But it's clear from the relative lack of 'official' recognition Urs had gotten, for instance [1], for having the largest hand in creating a piece of impressive scholarship, that some kind of journal run along the same lines and asking others to risk their careers is not going to be a roaring success. ([1] I mean: he took a job in the Middle East, not exactly Scholze-level career recognition :-)

Comment: Recall that 2012 was 'peak Elsevier', people were quite fired up and willing to think about new things, even if briefly. But look at a really serious attempt to change publishing by Fields Medallists at that time: _Forum of Mathematics: Pi_, which published three (3) articles last year, compared to the 33 in the _Annals_ (the intended competition), over 6 issues. (to compare: _FoM:Sigma_ published 24 last year, fairly respectable given the selective nature)

Comment: @David Roberts, thank you for your feedback. That was useful. I think your comments would deserve to be merged into an answer.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou ok, done :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is not an official nLab position, just my take]

Sadly, the current system of academia [actively disincentivises](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5206685/) such novel experiments. It's hard enough to set up a new journal to effectively replace a journal run by some for-profit shareholder-pleasing company, although it [has been](http://oad.simmons.edu/oadwiki/Journal_declarations_of_independence) and [can still be](https://blog.scholasticahq.com/post/how-to-start-flip-open-access-academic-journal/) done, with a lot of goodwill and determination by sub-communities of the mathematics world. Setting up a wiki-journal is even less respected.

The [Steering Committee of the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlabmeta/show/steering+committee) (which doesn't run it, officially) hasn't done a post-mortem, or tried to dig into why [the journal](https://ncatlab.org/publications/published/HomePage) didn't take off. But it's clear from the relative lack of 'official' recognition [Urs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urs+Schreiber) had gotten, for instance¹, for having the largest hand in creating a piece of impressive scholarship, that some kind of journal run along the same lines and asking others to risk their careers is not going to be a roaring success.

Recall that 2012 was '[peak Elsevier](http://thecostofknowledge.com/)', people were quite fired up and willing to think about new things, even if briefly. But look at [a really serious attempt](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/forum-of-mathematics-pi-and-forum-of-mathematics-sigma/) to change publishing by Fields Medallists at that time: *[Forum of Mathematics: Pi](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-pi)*, which [published three (3) articles](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-pi/volume/01F1E9B6DCF4D2EE542DC17AC8197077) last year, compared to the 33 in the *[Annals](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/)* (the intended competition), over 6 issues. (to compare: *[FoM:Sigma](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma)* published 24 last year, fairly respectable given the selective nature)

¹ I mean: he accepted [an affiliation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Urs_Schreiber) in the Middle East, in addition to his position in Prague, not exactly Scholze-level career recognition :-)

Comment: Personally, the conclusion that I came to is that it was not worth the (substantial) effort because it was not solving the right problem.  It might have been kind of neat to have a journal designed with wikilinks, but the real problem facing category theory journal-wise was (and to a certain extent still is) that we need free and open alternatives to the "most prestigious" proprietary journal options, not experimental journals that would have had an uphill battle to establish even the level of prestige of existing open journals like TAC.

Comment: I agree with Mike. It would be nice if there was an Advance in fancy Mathematics journals that a) accepted category theory papers and b) were not owned by Elsevier, or run by people who won't even countenance discussion of the problems in academic publishing.

Comment: I have been encouraged by the creation of journals like Higher Structures and Compositionality, which at least provide more options for publishing category theory papers in open journals.

Comment: @Mike yes, though they unfortunately aren't seen with the same magical shine as some. No doubt my career has not been helped by boycotting Elsevier. One paper in a certain journal of theirs would give me many more brownie points than I currently have, despite the research being identical.

Comment: Maybe the real solution is for us to boycott universities that rely on such ridiculous measures to determine tenure and promotion.  (-:O

Comment: "my career has not been helped by boycotting Elsevier": please consider continuing to boycott despite this.

Comment: @AndréHenriques don't worry, I'm sticking to it.

Comment: @MikeShulman. I have a solution. We should replace university mathematics research with cryptocurrency smart contracts that will reward people with tokens for solving computational problems. This will work exceptionally well for some highly computational applied areas of mathematics such as set theory and large cardinals, the most CPU intensive area of mathematics.

Comment: @MikeShulman see for instance this moderately depressing piece: "Almost half of research-intensive universities consider journal impact factors when deciding whom to promote, a survey of North American institutions has found." https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01151-4 (paper: https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.27638v2)